# how to calculate time difference with seconds : minutes : hours in sql?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, database

if I use sql syntax then the result is like this

`SELECT *, (TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,created_at,updated_at)) AS 'time_diff' FROM attendances;`

results in syntax like this

[image: Image SQL]

The sql syntax above only displays the hour data, I want to generate data like this **12 hours 10 minutes 20 seconds**

Comment: from the screenshot it becomes likely that you are using MySQL as your dbms. However, it’s not stated anywhere, so technically your question cannot be answered precisely

Comment: That’s (relatively) difficult to do in mysql and easy to do with php, there are relevant helpers in laravel too diffForHumans doesn’t suit your needs? Please update the question to _either_ tag the question correctly (no php tags, name the db in use) or refocus on php with the code you have tried to use.